# Why is sc.wholeTextFile().collect() slow

Tags: apache-spark

I'm using Spark2.1 local mode (local[4]) and try to call `sc.wholeTextFiles` to read news20 dataset as RDD:

`val rdd = sc.wholeTextFiles("~/20news-18828/*", 4)
val result = rdd.collect()`

The dataset is downloaded from here: http://qwone.com/%7Ejason/20Newsgroups/20news-18828.tar.gz and after uncompressing it, there will be 20 category folders under `20news-18828`. For each subfolder, there will be around 900 small text files and thus 18828 text files in total.
Currently the data is on my local machine and probably in the future I will read them from HDFS.

My problem is that calling `rdd.collect()` above is really slow, which takes around 90 seconds... Alternatively if I use local Java file API to read all of them as an array and then `sc.parallelize then collect`, it will finish almost immediately.

Wondering why using `sc.wholeTextFiles` is that slow? Or what I'm doing wrong? I'm just not familiar with Spark and any help will be appreciated!

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is slower than reading a local file because you are incurring overhead that is adding no value.

```
// read files into at least 4 partitions
// here you have the overhead of spinning up driver and executors and partitioning data
val rdd = sc.wholeTextFiles("~/20news-18828/*", 4)

// pull all of the data back from the executors and put it all on the driver
val result = rdd.collect()
```

to get the performance benefit of spark parallelism you need to process the data in parallel in some way.

Since you are just getting started with Spark I recommend starting with the newer DataFrame api rather than older low-level spark context / RDDs.